# Adding item in linked list C

Tags: c, list, input, linked-list

When i want to add item to linked list my program crashes.
This are my structs that i'm using

```
typedef struct seats
    {
    int number, reserved;
    char name[1000]; 
    } seats;
    // node list
    typedef struct node
    {
    seats seat;
    struct node * next;
    } node_t;
```

And this is my `insert` function

```
void AddSeat(node_t * head, seats a_seat) // unos podataka na kraj liste
    {
    node_t * current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    /* now we can add a new variable */
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->next->seat = a_seat;
    current->next->next = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add the code where you create the very first node for your list, and also the code where you are calling AddSeat?

Comment: You are trying to pass seats by value.   You need to pass a pointer to your routine.

Comment: You are succeeding in passing seats by value:)  Unfortunately, that is not what you need to do since you the nonly modify copies of the pointers:(

Comment: ...something you would have realized if you had run your app under your debugger.

Comment: This issue is not with `seats a_seat`, but like with `node_t * head`.  Post  initialization of the linked list and the first call to `addSeat()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think your logic is wrong.

In a linked list you start with an empty node:

`[ ]->`

When you have something to store you fill the node.

`[X]->`

**Then** you create a new empty node at the end of it.

`[X]->[ ]`

And so forth.. And so on..

`[X]->[X]->`

`[X]->[X]->[ ]`

In your code, you are adding the value to the new element. When you are at the **end** of the list you **assign the seat to the current node** and then **create a new (empty) node at the end**. You should also create a variable for the node, allocate memory for it and then point the node to it.

For the linked list to work, where you have

```
/* now we can add a new variable */
current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
current->next->seat = a_seat;
current->next->next = NULL;
```

you should have

```
void AddSeat(node_t *head, seats a_seat){
    node_t *current = head;
    node_t *new_node;

    ...

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->seat = a_seat;
    current->next = new_node;

    ...

}
```

Also please consider following some good practices when writing code in C like ataching the pointer operator (*) to the variable name (`char *var` instead of `char * var`) and properly indent your code. It improves readability a lot.